# Error: Unbound value PolkaGrid.manager_alloc_loose

Tags: ocaml, package

I am still trying to compile this file, by `ocamlc -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron -I /usr/local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/gmp/ -c file.ml`

```
open Apron;;
open Mpqf;;
open Format;;

let print_array = Abstract0.print_array;;
let lincons1_array_print fmt x =
  Lincons1.array_print fmt x
;;
let generator1_array_print fmt x =
  Generator1.array_print fmt x
;;

let manpk = Polka.manager_alloc_strict();;
let manbox = Box.manager_alloc ();;
let manoct = Oct.manager_alloc ();;
let manppl = Ppl.manager_alloc_strict();;
let mangrid = Ppl.manager_alloc_grid ();;
let maneq = Polka.manager_alloc_equalities ();;
let manpkgrid = PolkaGrid.manager_alloc_loose ();;
```

The errors in my previous threads have been resolved, now I am stuck with `Error: Unbound value PolkaGrid.manager_alloc_loose`. But I can find `polkaGrid.cmi`, `polkaGrid.cmxa` and some other files under `/usr/`:

```
...@ubuntu$ find -name "*polkaGrid*"
./lib/polkaGrid.cma
./lib/polkaGrid.cmi
./lib/polkaGrid.mli
./lib/polkaGrid.a
./lib/dllpolkaGrid_caml.so
./lib/libpolkaGrid_caml_debug.a
./lib/polkaGrid.cmxa
./lib/libpolkaGrid_caml.a
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/stublibs/dllpolkaGrid_caml.so
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/stublibs/dllpolkaGrid_caml.so.owner
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.cma
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.cmi
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.mli
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.a
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/libpolkaGrid_caml_debug.a
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.cmxa
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/polkaGrid.cmx
./local/lib/ocaml/3.11.2/apron/libpolkaGrid_caml.a
```

Does anyone know the reason of the error message? Thank you very much!

PS: about [PolkaGrid](http://apron.cri.ensmp.fr/library/0.9.10/mlapronidl/PolkaGrid.html)

Comment: As much as I'd like to believe documentation that the function in question is exposed, I don't. It is wise and easy to check that `polkaGrid.mli` file.

Comment: Effectively, the `PolkaGrid.mli` does not contain `manager_alloc_loose`. And I just realized that in the doc of PolkaGrid, the function is not exposed either. So that line of code must be wrong... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should replace

```
let manpkgrid = PolkaGrid.manager_alloc_loose ();;
```

by

```
let manpkgrid = PolkaGrid.manager_alloc manpk mangrid;;
```